# UISearchBar not updating

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uisearchbar

I have a `UIViewController`and I added `UITableViewController` in it and I am adding search bar programmatically. I am able to print the result after searching on the console but when I click on the search bar the custom table cells are still populated and search doesn't update them at all.

I have print statement in the `override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` to check if the search controller is active and it never prints that statement.

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class MasterViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate {

@IBOutlet var mTableView: UITableView!
var detailViewController: DetailViewController? = nil
var objects = [AnyObject]()
var resultSearchController = UISearchController()
var filteredData : NSMutableArray = []
var sectionInTable : NSMutableArray = ["Grand Haven 9", "Holland 7"]
var movieTitle : NSMutableArray = ["The Hunger Game 2","Creed"]
var movieTimeSection1 : NSMutableArray = ["11:00am, 11:40, 12:10pm, 1:25, 2:30, 6:05, 6:55, 7:30, 9:05", "11:10am, 11:50, 12:20pm, 2:25, 3:30, 6:05, 6:55, 8:30, 10:05"]
var movieTimeSection2 = ["Title": "Martian", "Theatre": "Holland 7", "Time": "11:00am, 11:40, 12:10pm, 1:25, 2:30, 6:05, 6:55, 7:30, 9:05"]


var onlineMovieTitle : NSMutableArray = []

var movieSection1 : NSMutableArray = []
var movieSection2 : NSMutableArray = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print(movieSection1)
    print(movieSection2)

    self.tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.cloudsColor()
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.cloudsColor()

    self.resultSearchController = ({
        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
        controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        controller.searchBar.delegate = self
        controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        controller.preferredStatusBarStyle() == UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
        controller.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        self.mTableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar

        return controller
    })()
    //self.resultSearchController.searchBar.endEditing(true)

}
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController){
    filteredData.removeAllObjects()

    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "Title CONTAINS %@", searchController.searchBar.text!.uppercaseString)
    let array = (movieSection1 as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
    let array2 = (movieSection2 as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
    //let array2 = (movieTimeSection1 as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
    filteredData.addObjectsFromArray(array)
    filteredData.addObjectsFromArray(array2)

    print(filteredData)
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.resultSearchController.searchBar.hidden = false
}

// MARK: - Segues

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {

        }

    }
}

// MARK: - Table View

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var count : Int = 0
    if (self.resultSearchController.active) {
        return 2
    }
    else {
        if section == 0 {
            count = movieSection1.count
        } else if section == 1 {
            count = movieSection2.count
        }
    }
    return count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : MainTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MainTableViewCell

    //Fancy Cells
    var corners : UIRectCorner = UIRectCorner.AllCorners
        if (tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(indexPath.section) == 1) {
            corners = UIRectCorner.AllCorners
        } else if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            corners = UIRectCorner.TopLeft.union(UIRectCorner.TopRight)
        } else if (indexPath.row == tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(indexPath.section) - 1) {
            corners = UIRectCorner.BottomLeft.union(UIRectCorner.BottomRight)
        }
    cell.configureFlatCellWithColor(UIColor.greenSeaColor(), selectedColor: UIColor.cloudsColor(), roundingCorners: corners)

    //Fancy Buttons
    cell.cornerRadius = 7
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        cell.trailorButton.addTarget(self, action: "openHunger:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    }else if indexPath.row == 1{
        cell.trailorButton.addTarget(self, action: "openCreed:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    }
    cell.trailorButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    cell.trailorButton.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    let movieNameStr = movieTitle[indexPath.row] as! String
    cell.movieImage.image = UIImage(named: movieNameStr)

    //Cell Data Insertion

    if (self.resultSearchController.active){
        print("search ---------------")
        cell.movieName.text = filteredData[indexPath.row].valueForKey("Title") as? String
        cell.movieDetail.text = filteredData[indexPath.row].valueForKey("Time") as? String
        return cell
    }else {
        print("cell")
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            cell.movieName.text = movieSection1[indexPath.row].valueForKey("Title") as? String
            cell.movieDetail.text = movieSection1[indexPath.row].valueForKey("Time") as? String
        } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
            cell.movieName.text = movieSection2[indexPath.row].valueForKey("Title") as? String
            cell.movieDetail.text = movieSection2[indexPath.row].valueForKey("Time") as? String
        }
        return cell
    }



    //return cell
}

@IBAction func openHunger(sender: AnyObject) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "https://youtu.be/n-7K_OjsDCQ")!)
}
@IBAction func openCreed(sender: AnyObject) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "https://youtu.be/fCBzWLVQgk8")!)
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return self.sectionInTable[section] as? String
}

}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Dereck .. toss one of these in the "updateSearchResultsForSearchController" dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  [self.contentView.tableView reloadData];
 }); .. this is objective-c so just translate this over to Swift. but I think you may just need to reload the tableView to see the results, but what the hell do I know, I don't use UISearchControllers or whatever they are called, I use UITextFields and do ti all manually.

Comment: OMG, I can't believe I deleted that line and thanks it was the problem. I can't believe I missed it after looking at it so many times. Do you want to post this as an answer so I can close it?

Comment: no problem, hopefully that's the only issue

Answer (score 0):

I missed it and thanks to Larcerax the problem was solved by adding `mTableView.reloadData()`